# What follows after a Mann-Whitney U Test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, group-differences

I have a statistically significant result for the Mann-Whitney U Test. The groups used are slightly overlapping so what i am interested in now is finding out the best splitting point between two groups.

[image]

So depending on T8-T6 i need to know when to use either the DECLINE type or the RECOVER type since there were a statistical difference here. How can i do this?

Just assume that every person, where the two groups overlapp, is in the DECLINE group. After that need to find the best point to split DECLINE and RECOVER.

ps: the result from DECAY and IMRPOVE are not significant and can be excluded from this question

Comment: What is your goal? It sounds like you want to predict group membership based on a measured value. Is that accurate?

Comment: @Dave i would say so! I split my data into groups to improve performance for my linear regression model. T8-T6 is a measured value available which i base my group membership on. If i can discern which group a person is in, my accuracy for the linear regression model will increase since the linear correlation is more evident.

Comment: Just assume that every person, where the two groups overlapp, is in the DECLINE group. After that find the best point to split DECLINE and RECOVER.

Comment: Have you drawn T8-T6 (whatever that is) against itself?  Do you not have anything else, such as T8 and T6, which might help distinguish the four types?

Comment: Unless there is no overlap, the probability of class membership is the appropriate goal, and can be estimated using logistic regression.